# how to disable /Qspectre using Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, docker, command-line

I tried to google it but couldn't find it. I want to Disable /Qspectre from command line.

> Note: I am trying this inside docker container i have already
> installed component for it.But still i am getting error MSB8040:
> Spectre-mitigated libraries are required for this project.So i want to
> disable it and give try. if it works.

```
docker run -v C:\BuildTools\ConsoleApplication1:C:\ConsoleApplication1 --name CP3 buildtools2019 msbuild C:\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.sln -maxcpucount:3 /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64
```

This is PowerShell command which i am using it to run my project. open for all suggestion and recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid there is no direct command line method to disable /Qspectre. I suggest that you could disable it by some other methods.

Put/copy file with name 'Directory.Build.props' to build folder with content:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Configuration">
    <SpectreMitigation>false</SpectreMitigation>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

That overrides default VS behavior and disables /QSpectre compiler switch.

You could refer to this [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/348985/installing-wdk-1809-enabled-spectre-mitigation-fla.html).

Comment: I can not use GUI inside docker. so don't have this option i have only option to disable it  using command line. i know this that i can disable it from here but i don;t about command line

Comment: I have revised the answer and hope it helps you.